# How to get a Histogram of PyTorch tensors in batches?

Tags: python, pytorch, histogram, tensor

Is there a way to get the histograms of torch tensors in batches?

For Example:
x is a tensor of shape `(64, 224, 224)`

```
# x will have shape of (64, 256)
x = batch_histogram(x, bins=256, min=0, max=255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this with `torch.nn.functional.one_hot` in a single line of code:

```py
torch.nn.functional.one_hot(data_tensor, num_classes).sum(dim=-2)
```

The rationale is that `one_hot` does respect batches and, for each value v in the last dimension of the given tensor, creates a tensor filled with 0s, with the exception of the v-th component, which is 1. We them sum over all such one-hot encodings to obtain how many times v appears in each row of data in the 2-nd last dimension (which was the last dimension in `tensor_data`).

One possibly serious drawback of this method is memory usage, since each value with be expanded into a tensor of size `num_classes` (so, the size of `tensor_data` is multiplied by `num_classes`). This memory usage is temporary, however, since `sum` collapses again this extra dimension and the result will typically be smaller than `tensor_data`. I say "typically" because if `num_classes` is much larger than the size of the last dimension of `tensor_data` then the result will be correspondingly larger.

Here's the code with documentation, followed by pytest tests:

```py
def batch_histogram(data_tensor, num_classes=-1):
    """
    Computes histograms of integral values, even if in batches (as opposed to torch.histc and torch.histogram).
    Arguments:
        data_tensor: a D1 x ... x D_n torch.LongTensor
        num_classes (optional): the number of classes present in data.
                                If not provided, tensor.max() + 1 is used (an error is thrown if tensor is empty).
    Returns:
        A D1 x ... x D_{n-1} x num_classes 'result' torch.LongTensor,
        containing histograms of the last dimension D_n of tensor,
        that is, result[d_1,...,d_{n-1}, c] = number of times c appears in tensor[d_1,...,d_{n-1}].
    """
    return torch.nn.functional.one_hot(data_tensor, num_classes).sum(dim=-2)
```

```py
def test_batch_histogram():
    data = [2, 5, 1, 1]
    expected = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    run_test(data, expected)

    data = [
        [2, 5, 1, 1],
        [3, 0, 3, 1],
    ]
    expected = [
        [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    ]
    run_test(data, expected)

    data = [
        [[2, 5, 1, 1], [2, 4, 1, 1], ],
        [[3, 0, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 1], ],
    ]
    expected = [
        [[0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0], ],
        [[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0], ],
    ]
    run_test(data, expected)


def test_empty_data():
    data = []
    num_classes = 2
    expected = [0, 0]
    run_test(data, expected, num_classes)

    data = [[], []]
    num_classes = 2
    expected = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    run_test(data, expected, num_classes)

    data = [[], []]
    run_test(data, expected=None, exception=RuntimeError)  # num_classes not provided for empty data


def run_test(data, expected, num_classes=-1, exception=None):
    data_tensor = torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.long)

    if exception is None:
        expected_tensor = torch.tensor(expected, dtype=torch.long)
        actual = batch_histogram(data_tensor, num_classes)
        assert torch.equal(actual, expected_tensor)
    else:
        with pytest.raises(exception):
            batch_histogram(data_tensor, num_classes)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the [Pytorch Issues#99719](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/99719#issuecomment-1664135524), you can do this by `torch.Tensor.scatter_add_`. `scatter_add_` is more memory efficient than `torch.nn.functional.one_hot`.

Similar to @user118967's answer:

```py
# https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/99719#issuecomment-1664135524 
def batch_histogram(data_tensor, num_classes=-1):
    """
    Computes histograms, even if in batches (as opposed to torch.histc and torch.histogram).
    Arguments:
        data_tensor: a D1 x ... x D_n torch.LongTensor
        num_classes (optional): the number of classes present in data.
                                If not provided, tensor.max() + 1 is used (an error is thrown if tensor is empty).
    Returns:
        A D1 x ... x D_{n-1} x num_classes 'result' torch.LongTensor,
        containing histograms of the last dimension D_n of tensor,
        that is, result[d_1,...,d_{n-1}, c] = number of times c appears in tensor[d_1,...,d_{n-1}].
    """
    maxd = data_tensor.max()
    nc = (maxd+1) if num_classes <= 0 else num_classes
    hist = torch.zeros((*data_tensor.shape[:-1], nc), dtype=data_tensor.dtype, device=data_tensor.device)
    ones = torch.tensor(1, dtype=hist.dtype, device=hist.device).expand(data_tensor.shape)
    hist.scatter_add_(-1, ((data_tensor * nc) // (maxd+1)).long(), ones)
    return hist
```

with the test cases in [Google colab here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rwd6LHgjWGC6kINnlQrUmbrZzLQMfalq?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but seems to me this is a hard thing to do and PyTorch does not have anything out-of-the-box.

The histogram is a statistical operation. It is inherently discrete and non-differentiable. Also, they are not vectorizable by nature. So, I don't think there is any easy way than a vanilla loop-based solution.

```
X = torch.rand(64, 224, 224)
h = torch.cat([torch.histc(x, bins=256, min=0, max=255) for x in X], 0)
```

If anyone has a better solution, feel free to post.

Comment: Is there a way to at least do it in numpy or any other frame work because those batches are going to be very huge

Comment: `numpy`'s histogram [function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy-histogram) works the same way as `PyTorch`. Notice it says "*computed over the flattened array*", that means it doesn't support batching. You can loop with numpy just like my torch example.